# Umlauts are not printed correctly when printed into document

Tags: r, officer

When printing a word file with the print() command, umlauts (ä,ö,ü) are not being printed correctly into the word file.

My R Studio is setup to save scripts as UTF-8.
I manually saved all files "encoded as UTF-8", after I find/replaced all umlauts with ae/oe/ue and back to ä/ö/ü again.
The officer package is set to use UTF-8.

Is there another setting (maybe in R itself) that has to be checked for successfull endocing when printing into a docx file?

EDIT:

I found the solution:
I was running the scripts with the source command, which doesn't have UTF-8 set as default.
This prints the umlauts (officer, .doxc)

```
source("path/to/script.R", encoding = "UTF-8" )
```

This one doesnt:

```
source("path/to/script.R", sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when r is dealing with non-english language.

Since I don't know your exact code,

1).
I suggest that you may try `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "")`

Set the locale to one that contains umlauts.

2).
Also, you may update your Rstudio to the latest version and then try:

Open:
(Menu bar) Tools-> Global Options-> Code (left bar) -> Saving

Set the default text encoding to proper one (UTF-8 for example)

Comment: 1) "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252 so it seems everything is set to German already

2. I use the most recent version and the text encoding is set to UTF-8. Any other ideas?

Comment: May I ask how you are trying to print your text? Rmarkdown, officeR or just print it on console?

Comment: Im using officer to print to .docx . I found the solution, thanks for all your help!